# Can you add Databricks jobs to a Git repo?

Tags: git, databricks, databricks-workflows

I'm trying to add databricks jobs to a git repo. I see you're able to run notebooks from a git repo in a job but I don't know if it's possible for the job itself to be added to a git repo.

Comment: Git knows nothing about databricks, and doesn't have a concept of jobs. Git stores commits; those commits store files; the commits are arranged into things we call branches, and you use branch names to help you find the commits (which then have your files) and that's all there is to the Git side of things.

Comment: From the databricks side, it appears that a [job](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/jobs/jobs.html) is *mainly* a blob of JSON, but to get databricks to *run* a job you must invoke some API endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not possible to "natively" save job definition into Git, but it could be done different ways:

- Using Databricks Terraform provider's `databricks_job` resource ([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/job)). The biggest advantage of using it is that it allows to handle dependencies to other resources, like, existing clusters, DLT pipelines, etc.  But it requires familiarity with Terraform. You can also export existing job(s) with dependencies using the Terraform Exporter functionality ([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/experimental-exporter)) using `-match` option to export selected job(s).
- Using Databricks Asset Bundles - this is relatively new functionality of [new Databricks CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/bundle-commands) that allows to describe a job plus resources using YAML file, and then deploy to workspace(s). See this [product tour](https://www.databricks.com/resources/demos/tours/data-engineering/databricks-asset-bundles) & [DAIS 2023 presentation](https://www.databricks.com/dataaisummit/session/databricks-asset-bundles-standard-unified-approach-deploying-data-products/) for more details.
- Export Databricks Job definition as JSON from UI, and then use that JSON definition with Databricks CLI or REST API. This method is most complex when you need to deploy a job with dependencies to other resources, so it's not recommended until you know what you're doing.

Comment: Currently the Terraform Exporter Functionality is in experimental state. Is it advised to use it in production or just use databricks_job provider. Also the existing workflows and notebooks cant be bundled and moved to prod ? Third options seems fine but what does dependencies on other resources mean ? Its just task inside workflow right ?

Comment: Exporter is used to generate `databricks_job` for existing resources and their dependencies. After that, you just use the generated Terraform code. It's marked as experimental just because we sometimes make changes that "may" be considered as breaking. But really we have customers who are using it to handle hundreds of thousands of Databricks objects (notebooks, ...). Regarding the 3rd option - dependencies in this case, for example, cluster policy ID, instance pool ID, etc. - they are specific for a given workspace

Comment: I know I am asking questions, but is the terraform exporter a one time thing or I can hook it into CI/CD pipeline and export terraform files everytime I want to deploy to prod ? I hope the terraform files are overwritten but the same state files are updated everytime its deployed to prod . If that happens , it will make my life easier . I dont have write custom scripts then and as you suggested I really hate the 3 option of JSON UI

Comment: It should work, but we can change, the exported resource name for example (one of the reasons for being experimental), and then the state won't match, leading to removal of original job & creation of new one

Answer (score 1):

The feature that you need was in Preview and have been recently made GA. It's also supported by the Terraform Provider

See https://databricks.com/blog/2022/06/21/build-reliable-production-data-and-ml-pipelines-with-git-support-for-databricks-workflows.html

Comment: it's another feature - from comments, it looks like author is looking for storing job definition inside repository, not use repository in job